# Unable to get property 'getSelectionModel' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

This is a non-consistent issue observed in IE 11.

I am running the application in IE. It works fine in other browsers.

there are some links available here which points to usage of meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I am already using this but then also facing the same issue. Also there are no trailing commas or spaces available in my code.

Please provide some pointers if you have faced this kind of issue anytime.

It does not provide the full stack trace. i can see the following error in console. I am using ExtJS 5.1.0

[image]

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace? Are you using the most recent patch of 5.x?

Comment: Updated my question with error image.

Comment: Where do you get this error ? On event ? Or view init  ?

Comment: This is on button click, but the error is logged as soon as i click on a button.

Comment: I have tried sencha fiddle and could not repeat the error in IE 11. Could you send the handler of button.

Answer (score 0):

this is  extjs 5.1.0.107 and i do not take any such errors .

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ech

When I looked at the code sencha uses microloader. Do you use any microloader ?

Comment: Yes i do user microloader which is Sencha's default one. Since this is a sporadic issue sometime it becomes difficult to reproduce it.

Comment: did you check css ? or sass ? if you can post button handler code and grid's.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue in fiddle and i cannot share the code because of some security issues. Basically i am using cellediting and rowExpander plugins in my grid. In button handler i am just validating the form and sending a post request to backend services. I guess this is the issue coming from editor plugin.